# How to display a length into minutes and seconds with a leading zero using printf()

Tags: java, printf

I am working on my second java program. I am creating a class called Song and a main class to test the Song class. My issue is in my method `public void songDisplay()` located in the Song class. The assignment calls for me to calculate `length` into `min` and `sec` using `/` and `%` operators and to output using `printf()`  while displaying a leading zero for seconds less than 10. I have tried to search how to do this and have failed. Any help would be appreciated!

An example of what I am looking to do would be for my method in the main class file my method `testdisplaymethod(title3)` the output should appear as follows  `"Blue Canadian Rockies" (The Byrds) 2:02`.

**Song Class**

```
public class Song {
    
    //declares private variables
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private int length;
            
    public Song(String songTitle,String songArtist,int songMin,int songSec){
        this.title = songTitle;
        this.artist = songArtist;
        this.length = (songMin * 60) + songSec;
        }
     public Song(){
        title = "untitled";
        artist = "unknown";
        length= 0;
     }

    //accessors
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
    public String getArtist(){
        return this.artist;
    }
    public int getLength(){
        return this.length;
    }

    //mutatators
    public void setTitle(String songTitle){
        this.title = songTitle;
    }
    public void setArtist(String songArtist){
        this.artist = songArtist;
    }
    public void setLength(int songLength){
        this.length = songLength;
    }
    public void songdisplay(){
        System.out.printf("\"%s\",(%s),", title, artist, length);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Main Class file to test Song class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // creates a default object to test default constructor
        Song title1 = new Song();
        testdefaultconstructor(title1);
       
        // creates a an object to test accessor/mutator methods
        Song title2 = new Song("For What It's Worth", "Buffalo Springfield",2,37
        );
        testfourparamconstructor(title2);
        
        //tests the display method
        Song title3 = new Song("Blue Canadian Rockies", "The Byrds", 2,2);
        testdisplaymethod(title3);
    }
    // tests the defaul constructor
    public static void testdefaultconstructor(Song title1){
        System.out.println("Testing default constructor");
        System.out.println("Title: "+ title1.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Artist: " + title1.getArtist());
        System.out.println("Length "+ title1.getLength());
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void testfourparamconstructor(Song title2){
        System.out.println("Testing four-paramameter constructor");
        System.out.println("Title: "+ title2.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Artist: " + title2.getArtist());
        System.out.println("Length "+ title2.getLength());
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void testdisplaymethod(Song title3){
        System.out.println("Testing Display Method");
        title3.songdisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify two digits with leading zeros the format specified is `%02d`. Change

```
System.out.printf("\"%s\",(%s),", title, artist, length); // <-- missing a format
System.out.println();
```

to

```
System.out.printf("\"%s\", (%s), %d:%02d%n", title, artist,
        length / 60, length % 60);
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I was close but just misplaced the characters.